# Why am I not able to cast the associations in the changeset?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to perform a transaction where I replace unique position values. When I reinsert the shows, the episodes don't attach even though I have preloaded them with the show and I am using cast_assoc in the changeset. Below are the files:

**show_controller.ex**

```
original_show = Repo.get!(Show, id)
|> Repo.preload(:episodes)

old_position = original_show.position
%{"position" => new_position} = show_params
new_position = String.to_integer(new_position)

query = from(s in Show, where: s.position <= ^new_position, where: s.position > ^old_position)
shows = Repo.all(query) |> Repo.preload(:episodes) |> Enum.sort(&(&1.position < &2.position))

result = Repo.transaction(fn ->
  Repo.delete!(original_show)
  Repo.delete_all(query)

  Enum.each shows, fn show ->
    show = Map.put(show, :position, show.position - 1)
    changeset = Show.changeset(show)
    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
     {:ok, show} -> show
     {:error, changeset} -> Repo.rollback(changeset)
    end
  end

  changeset = Show.changeset(original_show, new_show_params)
  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
   {:ok, show} -> show
   {:error, changeset} -> Repo.rollback(changeset)
  end
end)
```

**show.ex**

```
 def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
   struct
   |> cast(params, [:title, :position, :shuffle_episodes])
   |> cast_attachments(params, [:large_artwork_url, :parallax_artwork_url])
   |> cast_assoc(:episodes)
   |> validate_required([:title, :position, :large_artwork_url, :parallax_artwork_url, :shuffle_episodes])
   |> unique_constraint(:position)
 end
```

Comment: What if you change `changeset = Show.changeset(show)` to `changeset = Show.changeset(show, %{episodes: show.episodes})`?

Comment: @Dogbert I get the error `expected params to be a map, got: %Test.Episode{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "episodes">`

Comment: @Dogbert I made the episodes into a map and now I get `you are attempting to change relation :episodes of Test.Show, but there is missing data.`

Comment: @Dogbert After adding on_replace to `has_many :episodes, Test.Episode, on_replace: :nilify` in the Show schema, I now get a changeset error saying `errors: [show_id: {"can't be blank", []}]`